# Is it safe to add a little bleach to interior paint to kill bacteria?

Tags: paint

Is it safe to use bleach in in my interior paint to kill bacteria?
Is it safe to do so?

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what your goal is? Where do you expect bacteria to come from and why do you feel the need to kill them? Do you think that the paint is currently infested by dangerous bacteria and you want to sterilize it before it gets applied to the wall? Or do you expect that there will somehow be a long-term antibacterial effect on the walls after painting? (It certainly won't, bleach decomposes quite rapidly.)

Comment: Thank you for responding. It’s as simple as I did not properly cover this small amount of paint I have left.. My fault. But it is a tad smelly. Not very bad really, but a bit. lol that’s what I mean by bacteria, as I assume that’s the cause of the smell.

Comment: It’s not like rotten eggs, it’s not actually bad at all. But, it has changed. I know if not stored properly, it will sour. I tuouhht of a drop of bleach, but don’t want to kill myself accidentally. :)

Comment: *thought, pardon me.

Comment: I’d very much appreciate your help. It seems when I search it, that question has never been asked. lol, maybe that’s my answer there.. hahaa

Comment: It will depend on type of paint, but doubt bleach will do any good.  Paint not covered well will start to dry out and not be good for use.  Do not know if bacteria will grow on wet paint.

Comment: I'm far from expert, but AIUI, it's not bacteria, but mold that effects paint that sits. Bleach _will_ kill mold, but there's no reason to add bleach to the paint unless mold is visible (or smellable). Also, if there is mold growing, it seems that the best bet is to just chuck the paint as it's beyond use anyway. If the paint smells fine, it's going to be fine. If there's bacteria growing in it, well, it's probably no worse or better than the bacteria that was growing in the paint that was applied to your walls the last time they were painted. i.e. - you're worrying about nothing.

Comment: You can buy paint additives intended to prevent mold from growing on the painted surface. typically 1-2oz per gallon of paint. You'll find these in all the big orange/blue/whatever home stores and probably specialty paint stores too. Don't know if they'd be effective for bacteria, but I doubt that's really your problem anyway.

Comment: Bleach is a highly reactive chemical. It's unsafe to mix it with random chemicals. I don't even keep the stuff in my house. Do you imagine that the bleach will make the paint bacteria resistant after it dries on your walls? Or do you want to disinfect a gallon of paint for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

**Nobody knows. Depends on your definition of "safe".**

Adding a small amount of bleach to the paint will certainly not kill you (as long as you do it outside or in a well ventilated area), but it could easily ruin the paint. I don't think anyone can assure you that that won't happen, probably not even the manufacturer knows for sure. Perhaps try on a small sample first and see what happens.

Personally, I wouldn't do it unless I had 10+ litres of paint to salvage. Any less is probably not worth the hassle of eventually having to repaint a whole wall/room when the treated paint turns out to be not exactly working as intended later on. Also, adding bleach is probably not going to make it much less smelly than it is now (just replaces one smell with another).